# Async await building a mongoose query with many optional parts and then a final exec

Tags: javascript, inheritance, mongoose, async-await

I have some javaScript code that is calling a custom schema.static function defined on a mongoose schema and the call is being made by using async/await...

```
// =====================================
//
// =====================================
const insertNewRecord = async (report) => {

  console.log('111');
  const filter = { identity: report.identity, role: report.role, active: true };

  // default filter of record (by priority) - admin view, top 1 record
  const found = await Tests.getRecords(filter, undefined, true, 1); 

  if (!found) {
    console.log('222 - NOT FOUND SO INSERT');

    try {
      inserted = await Tests.create(report);
      if (inserted) {
         console.log('333 - Record Inserted', report);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('444 - ERROR ON POST', e);
    }

    console.log('555');
  }

  console.log('666');
}
```

I what to call a custom 'getRecords' method defined on the schema (via schema.statics) that does a number of property checks and then optionally attaches various statics functionality via chaining them onto the find query before finally calling exec() to execute the whole lot and get a result.

It looks for the existence of various static functionality defined on the sub-class in the schema file and if they exist (not all schema define them and they are seldom the same - even though the process of getting records is. It passes the query along allowing more optioned to chained or added in.

i.e.

```
// =====================================
// types of schema functionality present
// by schema.statics.<> in the schema...
// =====================================
schema.statics.poulateAdminList = query => {
  query
    .populate({
      path: 'configs',
      populate: {
        path: 'sensors',
        select: { _id: 1, ip: 1, ipv4: 1, plugin: 1, sensor: 1, auth: 1, timestamp: 1 },
      },
    })
    .populate({
      path: 'preferences',
    });
};

schema.statics.poulateList = query => {
  query
    .where({ active: true })
    .populate({
      path: 'configs',
      populate: {
        path: 'sensors',
        select: { _id: 1, ip: 1, ipv4: 1, plugin: 1, sensor: 1 },
      },
      select: { _id: 1, name: 1, active: 1 },
    })
    .populate({
      path: 'preferences',
      select: { _id: 1, theme: 1, tableColumns: 1 },
    })
    .select('identity email configs preferences role');
};

schema.statics.defaultSort = query => {
  query.sort({ priority: 1, identity: 1 });
};
```

Which is all `chained` together from the `BaseSchema`in the getRecords which each mongoose schema inherits.

```
// ============================================
// Defined in a base class that all schema have
// ============================================
async getRecords (where = {}, sort = null, admin = false, limit = 10) {
  const q = this.find(where);

  if (sort) {
    q.sort(sort);
  } else if (this.defaultSort) {
    this.defaultSort(q);
  }

  if (admin && this.poulateAdminList) {
    this.poulateAdminList(q);
  } else if (this.poulateList) {
    this.poulateListResponse(q);
  }

  // limit # of records
  q.limit(limit);

  // returns promise from q `find` but not exec() part ???
  return await q.exec();
},
```

When I call this
What I get consoled out on order is:

```
111
     <==== return too soon -looks like its the q but exec() not fired 
666
222 - NOT FOUND SO INSERT
333 - Record Inserted' { ... record stuff ... }
555
```

I know it's around the exec() / promise - but I really would like to be able to construct a query by chaining a number query element together and still await the answer before returning from the function getRecords

Does anyone have any idea how this chaining might be achieved and async used?

Comment: Unless you're using a very wonky transpiler and/or promise implementation, this output cannot happen from the code you posted. Maybe you were calling `insertNewRecord` multiple times and got interspersed logs from the two executions?

Comment: I would recommend to amend the `console.log('666');` by also logging the values of `found` and `inserted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by defining a small function to return a promise, that wrapped the exec()...

```
const execQueryAsync = query => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    query.exec((err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(doc);
    });
  });
};
```

can then I updated the last line of code in the getRecords function to call this new helper instead of just calling exec() directly...

like this:

```
async getRecords (where = {}, sort = null, admin = false, limit = 10) {
  const q = this.find(where);

  if (sort) {
    q.sort(sort);
  } else if (this.defaultSort) {
    this.defaultSort(q);
  }

  if (admin && this.poulateAdminList) {
    this.poulateAdminList(q);
  } else if (this.poulateList) {
    this.poulateListResponse(q);
  }

  // limit # of records
  q.limit(limit);

  // returns calling the helper instead of `exec()` directly
  return execQueryAsync(q);
},
```

Much simpler than I thought it was going to be, with a very small (next to no) impact on the design, functions of layout of the original code...

Comment: This should not be necessary. Just `return q.exec()` is enough, mongoose support promises natively.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a promise and wait for the function to resolve or use a callback function to return data.

For instance you can do something like this

```
    let a = Foo():
    a.then ( function onComplete (response) {
    //You can continue with your remaining functions here 
    }).catch ( function onError (error){
    console.log('Error', error);
    })

   Function Foo () {
     return new Promise ( function ( resolve, reject ) {
       Execute your query here.
     });
   }
```

As for the callback functions here is an example

```
function asyncOperation ( a, b, c, callback ) {
  // ... lots of hard work ...
  if ( /* an error occurs */ ) {
    return callback(new Error("An error has occurred"));
  }
  // ... more work ...
  callback(null, d, e, f);
}

asyncOperation ( params.., function ( err, returnValues.. ) {
  //This code gets run after the async operation gets run
});
```